# Can the Excel Power Query feature be used with .csv files with headers and other non-tabulated data?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, data-modeling

I'm trying to process 200 .csv files each of which has more than the maximum number of rows permitted in Excel. The .csv files follow the format show in the table below - there is a name entry followed by the data itself in a table with headers. This is then followed by another name with a corresponding table of data below it. The same list of names appear in each .csv file but the tables of data below them can vary in length. I would like to combine all the tables with the same name (eg. "chamber") across all the .csv files and perform pivot table-type functions on them such as averaging for the same coordinates, etc. Is it possible to use the Data Models / Power Query features to process these files or would they need some pre-processing in vba to get them in right format before Power Query can be used?

CSV format

[image: 1]

I originally created some vba code that does all the above processing using msoFileDialog feature to open and interrogate the .csv files but ran into the problem of the files being too long.

Comment: PowerQuery: Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder, 

_Microsoft documentation:_

> [Import data from a folder with multiple files (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the format of your CSV - you can use the following PowerQuery to clean-up and flatten one CSV:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\...\chamber.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=4, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    // Remove empty rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Column1] <> null and [Column1] <> ""),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Name", each if [Column1] = "[Name]" then #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Column1] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Name",{"Name"}),
    // Remove empty rows on Column 2 or data header
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each [Column2] <> null and [Column2] <> "" and [Column2] <> "Y [ m ]"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Index"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns","null",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column4"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Column1", "X [ m ]"}, {"Column2", "Y [ m ]"}, {"Column3", "Z [ m ]"}, {"Column4", "Yplus Based Heat Tran. Coef. [ W m^-2 K^-1]"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"X [ m ]", type number}, {"Y [ m ]", type number}, {"Z [ m ]", type number}, {"Yplus Based Heat Tran. Coef. [ W m^-2 K^-1]", type number}, {"Name", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

This will give you one flattened table with an extra column for "Name". Try this on one file first, get it to what you need it be. Then look at @taller's comment above to merge multiple files.

**Assumed CSV format**

```
[Name],,,
chamberA,,,
,,,
[Data],,,
X [ m ],Y [ m ],Z [ m ],Yplus Based Heat Tran. Coef. [ W m^-2 K^-1]
-2.90E-03,6.17E-02,-1.67E-02,null
2,22,222,null
3,33,333,null
,,,
,,,
[Name],,,
chamberB,,,
,,,
[Data],,,
X [ m ],Y [ m ],Z [ m ],Yplus Based Heat Tran. Coef. [ W m^-2 K^-1]
4,44,444,null
5,55,555,null
6,66,666,null
7,77,777,null
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work to combine all your CSV files into one, preserving original filename and Name in separate columns. It is agnostic to number of rows or columns. It assumes Name is in Row3 and Data titles in Row6.  You can adjust that with the two numerical items in the code.

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\Path\To\Folder\With\CSVs"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CSV", each Csv.Document([Content])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each 
    let a=[CSV],
    b = [Name],
    c = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.RemoveFirstN(a,5)), //data titles row 6
    d = Table.AddColumn(c,"Title", each a{2}[Column1]) //Name row 3 Column1
    in  Table.AddColumn(d,"Filename", each b)
),
#"Combined CSVdata" = Table.Combine(#"Added Custom1"[Custom])
in  #"Combined CSVdata"
```